# SqlDataAdapter as Object value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello guys I have got this SqlDataAdapter which finds the highest value:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();             
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select MAX (ID_K) FROM klient", spojeni);
SDA.Fill(dt);


spojeni.Close();
```

If it selects I need its  result add +1 and insert it as object value into this parameter.

```
prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", ); // here should be SDA +1
```

I tried to insert to object value whole SqlDataAdapter but it was nonsense. Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT ...` and `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: Yes, that is nonsense. What makes you think the SqlDataAdapter is a number?

Comment: @catfood 14 days learning how to c#/sql :-D ?

Comment: That would do it! Try one step at a time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method for getting this value because;

> Executes the query, and **returns the first column of the first row** in
>   the result set returned by the query.

Since your command returns only maximum value of `ID_K` column, that is exactly what we want.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select MAX (ID_K) FROM klient");
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(command, spojeni);
int max = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", max + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int maxID = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
prikaz2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", maxID + 1);
```